# How to change selection shape marker in "gdk_pixbuf_composite" with gtk c?

Tags: gtk, gtk3

I use this code for crop selection:

```
gboolean mouse_press_callback(GtkWidget      *event_box,
                              GdkEventButton *event,
                              gpointer        data)
{
    if (img1buffer == NULL)
        return TRUE;

    static gint press_x = 0, press_y = 0, rel_x = 0, rel_y = 0;

    GtkAllocation ebox;
    gint img1_x_offset = 0, img1_y_offset = 0;
    gtk_widget_get_allocation(event_box, &ebox);
    img1_x_offset = (ebox.width - width) / 2;
    img1_y_offset = (ebox.height - height) / 2;

    if (event->type == GDK_BUTTON_PRESS)
    {
        press_x = event->x - img1_x_offset;
        press_y = event->y - img1_y_offset;
        //g_print ("Event box clicked at coordinates %f,%f\n",
        //event->x - img1_x_offset, event->y - img1_y_offset);
    }
    else if (event->type == GDK_BUTTON_RELEASE)
    {
        rel_x = event->x - img1_x_offset;
        rel_y = event->y - img1_y_offset;
        //g_print ("Event box released at coordinates %f,%f\n",
        //event->x - img1_x_offset, event->y - img1_y_offset);

        dest_x = rel_x < press_x ? rel_x : press_x;
        dest_y = rel_y < press_y ? rel_y : press_y;
        dest_width = abs(rel_x - press_x);
        dest_height = abs(rel_y - press_y);

        // mark user selection in image
        GdkPixbuf *img1buffer_resized = gdk_pixbuf_scale_simple(img1buffer, width, height, GDK_INTERP_TILES);
        gdk_pixbuf_composite(croppic, img1buffer_resized, dest_x, dest_y, dest_width, dest_height, 0, 0, 1, 1, GDK_INTERP_TILES, 170);
        gtk_image_set_from_pixbuf(GTK_IMAGE(img1), img1buffer_resized);
    }

    return TRUE;
}
```

that in main function:

```
croppic = gdk_pixbuf_new_from_file("E:/Works for Gov Project/DOC/GUI/logogui1/crop_bg.png", NULL);

img1 = gtk_image_new();
event_box = gtk_event_box_new();
gtk_event_box_set_visible_window(GTK_EVENT_BOX(event_box), FALSE);
gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(event_box), img1);
gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(frame1), event_box);

g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT(event_box), "button_press_event", G_CALLBACK(mouse_press_callback), NULL);
g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT(event_box), "button-release-event", G_CALLBACK(mouse_press_callback), NULL);
```

and "crop_bg.png" is:

[image]

But I want to a selection shape similar to in paint software:

[image]

What ideas on how to solve this task would you suggest? Or on what resource on the internet can I find help?

Comment: So which is it, gtk3 or gtk2? The answer is wildly different for both.

Comment: @ andlabs , It is in gtk3.

Comment: You don't need to use GDK composition with that. Instead, use cairo and override `::draw`. Then you can create a dashed stroke rectangle like that. Do you understand what I mean, before I post an answer?

Comment: @ andlabs, Thank you so much for your post. If it possible  insert a sample c code.

Comment: @ andlabs, I try to create a dashed stroke rectangle with gtk+3 in c, But I don't know how to change "GDK composition" to it??

Comment: You don't use GDK composition; you use cairo and the `draw` signal. I'll post an example later today.

Comment: @ andlabs,  I'm new in this part and If it possible write a sample code for guide me. thank you so much.

Comment: Yes, I haven't forgotten; I'm just getting to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to draw on top of a GtkImage. This isn't the best way to do custom drawing, and as you've noticed, `gdk_pixbuf_composite()` is rather limited.

Instead, you'll want to do drawing [the proper way](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/ch01s05.html), using the `::draw` signal and cairo. cairo is the vector graphics library that GTK+ 3 uses to draw its own widgets, and the `::draw` signal gives you a cairo context to draw with:

```
gboolean draw(GtkWidget *widget, cairo_t *cr, void *data);
```

cairo itself is easy to use; it's [well documented](https://www.cairographics.org/documentation/) and has [a whole bunch of samples](https://www.cairographics.org/samples/). What you want to do for your purposes is make a dashed stroked rectangle.

In addition, instead of using a GtkImage, you'll want to use [GtkDrawingArea](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/unstable/GtkDrawingArea.html). GtkDrawingArea is specifically designed to be drawn on, and with a little extra work can be made to handle your events.

The last piece of the puzzle, then, is how do you start drawing when the mouse events come in? You don't get a `cairo_t` in `button-press-event` or `button-release-event`, so you can't draw there. Indeed, GTK+ is optimized so that it only draws when necessary. To indicate that it's necessary to draw, you can use the `gtk_widget_queue_draw()` method. There are variations on this method that mark only a subset of the widget to be redrawn (you can get this subset back with `cairo_clip_extents()` from within the `::draw` handler).

Remember that widget coordinates are floating-point; so are cairo coordinates.

Let's demonstrate. I'm going to use global variables for this; you probably don't want to.

```
gdouble x0, y0;
gdouble x1, y1;
```

These will store the endpoints of the rectangle. When we press the mouse button, we want to start the drawing:

```
gboolean button_press_event(GtkWidget *widget, GdkEventButton *e, gpointer data)
{
    // ...
    x0 = e->x;
    y0 = e->y;
    x1 = e->x;    // start with a zero-sized rectangle
    y1 = e->y;
    // ...
}
```

When we move the mouse, we want to change `x1` and `y1` to the new mouse coordinates, and then update the rectangle. To optimize things, we'll only update the area that changed:

```
gboolean motion_notify_event(GtkWidget *widget, GdkEventMotion *e, gpointer data)
{
    // ...
    // first queue both old and new rectangles for drawing
    gtk_widget_queue_draw_area(widget,
        x0, y0,
        MAX(x1, e->x), MAX(y1, e->y));
    // then set the new rectangle
    x1 = e->x;
    y1 = e->y;
    // ...
}
```

You can probably figure out what to do on `button-release-event` from the above. `draw` would look something like

```
gboolean draw(GtkWidget *widget, cairo_t *cr, gpointer data)
{
    // ...
    cairo_rectangle(cr, x0, y0, x1 - x0, y1 - y0);
    // set up a dashed solid-color stroke
    cairo_stroke(cr);
    // ...
}
```

Good luck!

Comment: @ andlabs: Thank you so much for your post. I edit my question and add c++ code to end of it. But I don't know how change or improve "gboolean mouse_press_callback" function and c++ cod in main function with your new function.